# Problem using SetFetchMode in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

i have this method:

```
    public IEnumerable<Album> GetAllAlbumsWithTracks()
    {
        var albums = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Album))
            .SetFetchMode("Tracks", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).Future<Album>();

        return albums;
    }
```

but if i set .SetMaxResult(10) i get back 10 Tracks not Albums.  how do i fix this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221482/nhibernate-eager-loading-collections-paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the fetch mode to join

Comment: if i don't add SetMaxResult i get back everything in a single query.
if i set FetchMode.Join & SetMaxResult then i get Tracks.
if i set FetchMode.Select & SetMaxResult then i get Albums but i get
Select N + 1 not a single query.

how do i get 10 Albums in a single query?